# VB.NET How to resize labeltext without changing the other font settings

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I have a settings screen with a label and in this screen i also have a fontdialog.

What i'm trying to do is the following:

I set my font, size and other settings with my dialog.

On my second screen i want a label to show some tekst with those settings but only another size.

I used the following code:

```
Dim URLLabel As New Label
URLLabel.Text = Main.Label7Recieverinfo.Text
URLLabel.Name = "URL"
URLLabel.Font = My.Settings.TextFont
URLLabel.ForeColor = My.Settings.TextColor
URLLabel.BackColor = My.Settings.BackgroundColor
URLLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Top
URLLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
URLLabel.AutoSize = False
URLLabel.Height = 70
PanelTransmit.Controls.Add(URLLabel)
```

My problem is, the label shows my font, size and color       correctly but how can i use the font and style from My.settings.textfont   but with another size without changing it in my settings

sorry for my bad english

Comment: `URLLabel.Font = New Font(My.Settings.TextFont.FontFamily, new_size, My.Settings.TextFont.Style)`?

Comment: `URLLabel.Font = My.Settings.TextFont.Size+4` maybe?

Comment: Take care with that.  Fonts and Label are IDisposable

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in .net - i mostly work in VB6 but this should work...

```
Dim fnt As Font

fnt = TextBox1.Font

TextBox1.Font = New Font(fnt.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
```